# Why I get another reference each time I call IEnumerable.Last()

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I've a enumerable (`theEnumerable`) containing several items (of reference type).

The following expression `theEnumerable.Last() == theEnumerable.Last()` evaluate to `false`.

where:

```
theEnumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, x).Select(x => new T())
```

Why is that?

Comment: @Psddp Then it's creating new items each time it's iterated.  Apparently those newly created items aren't equal to each other.

Comment: @Servy You mean each time I call `.Last()`, the items in the enumerable are re-created?

Comment: @Psddp Each time you call last you execute the query, and you've defined the query as creating a new item.

Comment: This clears a big misconception  I had about IEnumerable, I assumed they are the same as IList.
Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to OP comments. Enumerable is created as following:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, x).Select(x => new T())
```

So what happens when you do `theEnumerable.Last() == theEnumerable.Last()` is that you enumerate `theEnumerable` twice, meaning that this `Select` lambda `x => new T()` is executed each time you iterate over `theEnumerable`, meaning that each iteration it will produce different results hence the confusion.

If you want your code to work like you expect it to work. Do the following.

```
var list = theEnumerable.ToList() // iterate once
list.Last() == list.Last() // I don't see how this makes sense, but I guess you have your own logic
```

Comment: Would adding equality operators to the class work as well?

Comment: @mjwills, yes it should, but then the code will be inefficient

Answer (score 4):

Not all sequences are obligated to return the same values, in the same order.  Sequences can produce different values each time they're iterated, or yield the values in a different order.

It's also possible that the type in question has an overloaded equality operator that results in an object not being equal to itself.  Types *shouldn't* ever do that, but they technically can.